# How to Parse and convert JSON to multidimensional array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have multiple JSON data like

```
var resultJSON = 
   '{"l":"1","p":"1","name":"john"},
    {"l":"1","p":"2","name":"john1"},
    {"l":"1","p":"2","name":"john2"}';
```

So Now,

I want to generate multidimensional array using jquery

```
resultJSON.each(function(){
var result = $.parseJSON(resultJSON);
    obj[1][1] = array("john");

}
```

How can I generate multidimensional array and if array has common key append the name?

OUTPUT will be:

```
 obj[1][1] = array("john");
 obj[1][2] = array("john1","john2");
```

Comment: can add your expected result?

Comment: @vsogrimen : yes updated.

Comment: You can use `push(yourVal)` to add elements to Array

Comment: @erikscandola : i tried push but its not generating key value pair i need

Comment: In your case, what's the key?

Comment: @erikscandola: key in array is the value of first and second object(l and p) in json.

Comment: You can check if your array contains value at position `[l]` and if yes check if contains value at position `[l][p]` and if yes push value at this position else add new array at position l and then push your value. I hope I explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your JSON is not an array, so you shold add square brackets.

Moreover you should check for each level of your final array, if the value exists and eventually initialize an array and push the name inside  it.

```
var results = $.parseJSON('['+resultJSON+']');
var obj = [];
$.each(results, function(i, res){
    var l = res.l, p = res.p;
    if(!obj[l]) obj[l] = [];
    if(!obj[l][p]) obj[l][p] = [];
    obj[l][p].push(res.name)
});
```

You can find a snippet here:

```js
var resultJSON = '{"l":"1","p":"1","name":"john"}, {"l":"1","p":"2","name":"john1"},{"l":"1","p":"2","name":"john2"}';

var results = $.parseJSON('['+resultJSON+']');
var obj = [];
$.each(results, function(i, res){
    var l = res.l, p = res.p;
    if(!obj[l]) obj[l] = [];
    if(!obj[l][p]) obj[l][p] = [];
    obj[l][p].push(res.name)
});

$('#output1').text(JSON.stringify(obj));
$('#output2').text(JSON.stringify(obj[1][2]));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<output id="output1"></output>
<br>
<output id="output2"></output>
```

---

EDIT

Alternative way:

```
var obj = {};
$.each(results, function(i, res){
  var l = res.l, p = res.p;
  if(!obj[l]) obj[l] = {};
  if(!obj[l][p]) obj[l][p] = [];
  obj[l][p].push(res.name)
});
//output {"1":{"1":["john"],"2":["john1","john2"]}}
```

Comment: Thanks, just one more thing, after creating multidim obj how can i stringify it? JSON.stringify not working.

Comment: It is not working? What do you expect to have in output?

Comment: It is giving result with multiple null values whereas i need proper string

Comment: Yes, sure! It is because obj[0][0] and obj[0][1] are not explicited. You should start from 0 in arrays :)

Comment: any solution of this issue?

Comment: @BhumiShah I have added something in my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
var src=[{"l":"1","p":"1","name":"john"},
         {"l":"1","p":"2","name":"john1"},
         {"l":"1","p":"2","name":"john2"}];

var obj={};
$.each(src,function(i,v){
  if (!obj[v.l]) {obj[v.l]={};obj[v.l][v.p]=[v.name]}
  else if (!obj[v.l][v.p]) obj[v.l][v.p]=[v.name]
  else obj[v.l][v.p].push(v.name);
})
```

The only jquery element in this is the `$.each()` method which you can even replace by the Array method `.forEach()` (the order of the anonymous function arguments must be changed then).